# Any way to change a Fluent WPF value in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my app, when i try to go fullscreen, the `Fluent WPF` titlebar stays there. I can remove it in xaml with `fw:AcrylicWindow.AcrylicWindowStyle="None"`, but I want to do it in c#.

Comment: You can not set `AcrylicWindowStyle = AcrylicWindowStyle.None;`?

Comment: @Clemens No, it just says that is a type, and that it can not be used like a variable.

Comment: In case your window is an AcrylicWindow , it should have an AcrylicWindowStyle property. See [Line 515 here](https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF/blob/master/FluentWPF/AcrylicWindow.cs)

Comment: @Clemens Yea but I can't really asign any of them...